# Unable to scroll pages vertically on Google Chrome "12.0.742.100"

Tags: google-chrome, vertical-scrolling

Unable to scroll pages vertically on Google Chrome "12.0.742.100", using the scroll-bar thumb, however I can use mouse scroll and also scroll the page using the up and down arrow keys.

Important points:

1. If I re-size the window such that there is a horizontal scroll-bar, the vertical scroll-bar starts to works fine, but if I re-size/there is no horizontal scroll-bar, the vertical scroll-bar thumb fails to work.
2. If I stop loading the page/try to scroll while the page is loading, it works fine.
3. The issue is reproducible on almost all the pages of my client's website "http://www.charlotterusse.com/", like:

   - http://www.charlotterusse.com/home/index.jsp
   - http://www.charlotterusse.com/category/index.jsp?categoryId=4078197
   - http://www.charlotterusse.com/family/index.jsp?categoryId=4335463&cp=4078197
   - http://www.charlotterusse.com/category/index.jsp?categoryId=4238904
   - http://www.charlotterusse.com/category/index.jsp?categoryId=4238909&cp=4238904

but, the following pages scroll just fine:

- http://www.charlotterusse.com/sitemap/index.jsp
- https://www.charlotterusse.com/checkout/index.jsp?process=login
- http://www.charlotterusse.com/helpdesk/index.jsp
- http://www.charlotterusse.com/storeLocator/index.jsp
- http://www.charlotterusse.com/giftCenter/index.jsp

It may be due to some conflict with Flash or JavaScript, but the site works fine on all other browsers and not chrome.

Please advice what could the issue be and how can it be fixed.

Comment: is it your website or you're google chrome programmer...?

Comment: I am a web developer and the website is of my client, who reported this issue. I assume it's an issue with this version of Google Chrome as there were issues with some earlier versions, but Client is adamant and does not want to upgrade, unless I could prove that it's not a design issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately found the solution for this issue. There was a JS code which was hindering the normal mousedrag actions.